# How to inspect HTTP requests made by my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, net-http

I want to see what I'm actually `POST`ing when executing a `Net::HTTP::Post` from my Rails app, headers and all. How can I inspect the actual request the app is making?

Comment: I believe you get the request object back when you call this: you can then call `inspect` on it and log the results.  Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see that at your view then you can do:

```
 <%= request.env.inspect %>
```

If you want to do that using logger at controller:

```
def show
    logger.info request.env
  end
```